# What are the alternatives to overriding asType() when writing conversion code?

Tags: grails, groovy

It appears the convention for converting objects in Groovy is to use the `as` operator and override `asType()`. For example:

```
class Id {
    def value

    @Override
    public Object asType(Class type) {
        if (type == FormattedId) {
            return new FormattedId(value: value.toUpperCase())
        }
    }
}

def formattedId = new Id(value: "test") as FormattedId
```

However, Grails over-writes the implementation of `asType()` for all objects at runtime so that it can support idioms like `render as JSON`.

An alternative is to re-write the `asType()` in the Grails Bootstrap class as follows:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    Id.metaClass.asType = { Class type ->
        if (type == FormattedId) {
                return new FormattedId(value: value.toUpperCase())
        }
    }
}
```

However, this leads to code duplication (DRY) as you now need to repeat the above in both the Bootstrap *and* the Id class otherwise the `as FormattedId` will not work outside the Grails container.

What alternatives exist to writing conversion code in Groovy/Grails that do not break good code/OO design principals like the Single Responsibility Principal or DRY? Are Mixins are good use here?

Comment: Why don't you just provide another public method to return what you want?

Comment: @JinzhaoWu that is a possible solution, however I feel it breaks the Single Responsibility Principle. Now the Id class is not only responible for representing and Id but also for handling conversions to an otherwise un-related class. Although, this is the same problem with the asType method.

Comment: This issue seems related: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3637

Comment: Which scope do you want this customized `as` operator to handle, only Id objects or global?

Comment: @JinzhaoWu preferably only Id to FormattedId, hence the re-implementation in the Id class.

Comment: OK. So why do you need to rewrite `as` operator? I think `idInstance.value.toUpperCase()` will be just fine.

Comment: @JinzhaoWu Rewriting the 'as' operator seems like the conventional Groovy way to proceed. The example I wrote above was deliberately trivial, but they idea is to make conversions re-usable outside of the example above. Also this breaks the SRP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Grails support for [Codecs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#codecs) to automatically add `encodeAs*` functions to your Grails archetypes:

```
class FormattedIdCodec {

    static encode = { target ->
        new FormattedId((target as String).toUpperCase()
    }

}
```

Then you can use the following in your code:

```
def formattedId = new Id(value: "test").encodeAsFormattedId
```

Comment: Not sure if this solution is entirely appropriate for the use case: Grails Codecs appear to be a security feature and aren't for everyday conversions.

Comment: there is encodeAsJson for example, which is not security related

Answer (score 0):

My un-elegant solution is to rename the original asType(), and make a new asType() that calls it, and to also make your BootStrap overwrite astType with a call to that method:

so, your class:

```
class Id {
    def value

    @Override
    public Object asType(Class type) {
        return oldAsType(type);
    }

    public Object oldAsType(Class type) {
        if (type == FormattedId) {
            return new FormattedId(value: value.toUpperCase())
        }
    }
}
```

In my app, I had asType defined in a number of classes, so I ended up using a common closure in BootStrap.groovy:

```
    def useOldAsType = {Class clazz ->
        delegate.oldAsType(clazz)
    }

    Id.metaClass.asType = useOldAsType;
    Value.metaClass.asType = useOldAsType;
    OtherClass.metaClass.asType = useOldAsType;
    SubclassOfValue.metaClass.asType = useOldAsType;
```

Note that if you have a subclass that does not override asType, but you want it to use the superclass's, you must also set it in BootStrap.